# ngDialog.open undefined - what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It works with directives in html, but when I try to open directly from controller, I get this result:

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ngDialog.open')
lightbox@xyz.com:3000/assets/projects.js?body=1:17:17
...

What does it mean??

```
   var app = angular.module('projects',['ngDialog']);

   var controller = function($scope,ngDialog){

/***********
 * methods *
 ***********/
    $scope.lightbox = function(name){
            ngDialog.open({ template: 'example' });
    };


};

app.controller('projectsCtrl',['$scope',controller]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't inject `ngDialog` service into your controller -- change the last line to:

```
app.controller('projectsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', controller]);
```